# VBA select text from mail body

Tags: vba, email, outlook, copy

I want to copy the entire body of an email message.
I used this code (wich I found somewhere and modified myself) and it works from time to time.
The problem is that the mail window is not activated each time => the code selects other things from the active winwow.
How can I get it right?

I tried `AppActivate ("Microsoft Outlook")` but it doesn't work.

```
Private Sub copymail()

    Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
    Dim objInspector As Outlook.Inspector

    Dim strDateTime As String

    ' Instantiate an Outlook Application object.
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    ' The ActiveInspector is the currently open item.
    Set objExplorer = objOutlook.ActiveExplorer

    ' Check and see if anything is open.
    If Not objExplorer Is Nothing Then
        ' Get the current item.
        Dim arySelection As Object
        Set arySelection = objExplorer.Selection

        For x = 1 To arySelection.Count
            Dim m As MailItem
            Set m = arySelection.Item(x)
            m.Display
            'DoEvents
            'DoEvents
            Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:02 AM#)
            'AppActivate ("Microsoft Outlook")
            SendKeys ("^a^c")
            DoEvents
            Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:01 AM#)

        Next x

    Else
        ' Show error message with only the OK button.
        MsgBox "No explorer is open", vbOKOnly
    End If

    ' Set all objects equal to Nothing to destroy them and
    ' release the memory and resources they take.
    Set objOutlook = Nothing
    Set objExplorer = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "It doesn't work". Do you get an error of somekind? Or does simply nothing happen?

Comment: Sening keys to read email message is poor solution. Read email message by opening each mail: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861332%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: I don't like it either, but how do i select the text body without sendkeys

Comment: the code is going through all items of the currently open outlook-Folder, intead of just one mail.

Comment: The code is displaying only the selected email. The problem is that the email window is not staying activated all time, so the sendkeys act on other windows instead of the email window.

Comment: How do I keep the email window activated, so the sendkeys act on it?

Answer (score 2):

You can access the mailbody through the MailItem.Body (plain text) or MailItem.HTMLBody (HTML) properties. No need to use SendKeys:

```
Sub getMailtext()

    Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
    Dim objInspector As Outlook.Inspector

    Dim strDateTime As String

    ' Instantiate an Outlook Application object.
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    ' The ActiveInspector is the currently open item.
    Set objExplorer = objOutlook.ActiveExplorer

    ' Check and see if anything is open.
    If Not objExplorer Is Nothing Then
        ' Get the current item.
        Dim arySelection As Object
        Set arySelection = objExplorer.Selection

        For x = 1 To arySelection.Count
            Dim m As MailItem
            Set m = arySelection.Item(x)

            Debug.Print m.Body
            Debug.Print m.HTMLBody

        Next x

    Else
        ' Show error message with only the OK button.
        MsgBox "No explorer is open", vbOKOnly
    End If

    ' Set all objects equal to Nothing to destroy them and
    ' release the memory and resources they take.
    Set objOutlook = Nothing
    Set objExplorer = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I didn't know about HTMLBody. But how do I copy the formatted body into my Excel sheet. If I copy the HTMLBody I only get a cell with the HTML code of the body. Instead, I need a sheet with the formatted text of the mail (with tables, hyperlinks, etc.).

Comment: @user3254924 Please post a new question for that. We will be happy to assist.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook uses Word as an email editor. You can use the Word object model for making manipulatins on the message body. The WordEditor property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Document class (from the Word object model) which represents the body. You can read more about that way and all possible ways in the [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012.aspx).